# Editing PDF files from a list, from half a page to get a whole page from that one half

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, macos

I have a PDF file that looks like this

```
----------
||----|  |
||----|  |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|________|
```

with the help of the following commands

```
$ convert -density 300 -quality 100 -crop 0x50% in.pdf out.png
$ ls
in.pdf, out-0.png, out-1.png
```

```
$ montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x out-0.png out-0.png out.pdf
$ ls
in.pdf, out-0.png, out-1.png out.pdf
```

I get a document like this

```
----------
||----|  |
||----|  |
|        |
||----|  |
||----|  |
|________|
```

Then I need to print it and then delete that PDF document.

**How do I achieve the same effect with a given list of files?**

```
$ cat list-of-pdfs.txt
file 1.pdf
file 2.pdf
file 3.pdf
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pair of commands that work on a single file `in.pdf`, generating `out.pdf` as its result:

> ```
> convert -density 300 -quality 100 -crop 0x50% in.pdf out.png
> montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x out-0.png out-0.png out.pdf
> ```

Because we're going to be applying the change to several files we cannot use fixed names, so we'll assume we're given the source file and then generate the destination file name:

```
file=in.pdf                  # in.pdf
dest=${file%.pdf}-out.pdf    # in-out.pdf

convert -density 300 -quality 100 -crop 0x50% "$file" "$dest"
montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x out-0.png out-0.png "$dest"
```

I don't know whether the `out-0.png` images are supposed to be the same for every file you want to process or named to match the outputs so I'll leave those as constants.

Now we need to apply the effect to each of the files in turn. The normal structure for this would be a `for` loop, but since you have the files in a list we'll use a `while` loop instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file
do
    # Apply your changes to the "$file"
    #
    dest="${file%.pdf}-out.pdf"
    echo "Processing $file into ${dest##*/}" >&2

    convert -density 300 -quality 100 -crop 0x50% "$file" "$dest"
    montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x out-0.png out-0.png "$dest"

done <list-of-pdfs.txt
```